# Can an external jar access a file within a folder in a project

Tags: java, jar

I am using an external jar (stored in my lib file within an eclipse project) and that jar needs access to a file to which I am supposed to pass the path. So far I have only been able to make it work properly if I store the file in a completely separate area on the server.

I'd like to be able to store this file neatly within the project. For examples sake lets say that testfile.txt is in the projects src/testfolder. From within java I try to reference the file like so:

```
File file = new File("src/testfolder/testfile.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

But that returns a path on my pc. In this case its:

```
"/home/me/testfolder/testfile.txt"
```

I'd like to application to be portable so I can move the jar file around if necessary without having to worry about bringing external folders. How can I reference this file within the application and pass that url to an external jar?

Answer (score 0):

Does the jar includes this file as well. If yes, then it should not be an issue as the absolute path will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: No...the external jar references a file located on the server. I am responsible for passing the external jar a path to the file, but I haven't had much luck getting it to work unless I store the file on my machine outside of the applications jar.